# average case complexity of ternary search

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, big-o, average

I need to solve for the average case complexity of ternary search.  In the worst case you would do two comparisons so I assume worst case complexity looks like this:

```
C(n) = C(n/3) + 2
```

which can then be shown to be O(logn), however what would the average case look like?  I'm thinking possibly this:

```
C(n) = C(n/3) + 1.5
```

since on average you might do 1 or 2 comparisons so (1+2)/3 = 1.5

Comment: Doesn't ternary search *always* perform two lookups on each iteration?

Comment: @templatetypedef Why would you need to? `if (e < data[n/3]) look left else if (e < data[2n/3]) look mid else look right` (well, a little more complex to take into account equality, but the same number of comparisons).

Comment: I think you are confusing a ternary search TREE with ternary search.  Your question and clarification make sense for a tree, but not for regular ternary search.

Comment: @ChrisOkasaki I agree, that's why the question threw me off to begin with... the big O complexity will never change for ternary search just the constant factor.

Answer (score 1):

If we are both talking about searching an element is a sorted array, I think in average you will have to do 5/3 comparisons.
Let's say you first check whether your element to be found x is higher or lower than the element placed in A(n/3) where A is your sorted array and n its length.
Statistically, since 1/3 of the elements are lower than A(n/3), and 2/3 are higher, x has a 1/3 chance to be lower and a 2/3 chance to be higher.
If x is lower, you don't need to the the second comparison, so you only need 1.
Is x is higher, you will need to compare it with A(2n/3), so you will need 2.
So in average, you will need (1/3)*1+(2/3)*2 = 5/3.

But that doesn't change anything for the global complexity, which will always be O(log n). The only difference will be the constant factor.